# POST Request is turning to 200 OPTIONS in Phoenix but not sending the following POST

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using Angular 2 and Phoenix and I'm trying to send a `POST` request to Phoenix. I have the following code:

#### endpoint.ex

```
plug Corsica, origins: "http://localhost", allow_headers: ["content-type"]
```

and in my frontend I have

```
@Injectable()
export class RegisterService {

    public headers: Headers;

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }

    createUser(): Observable<Response> {
        return this._http.post(
            'http://localhost:4000/v1/users', 
            JSON.stringify({
                firstName: 'lll',
                lastName: 'xxxxx',
                email: 'dddd@gmail.com',
                password: 'test123'
            }), 
            {headers: this.headers}
        );
    }
}
```

And here is the component code

```
createUser(): void {
    this._registerService.createUser().subscribe();
}
```

I get a 200 OK OPTIONS but it never sends the POST request.

### General

```
Request URL:http://localhost:4000/v1/users
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:4000
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

### Response Headers

```
cache-control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
content-length:0
date:Sat, 10 Jun 2017 04:29:50 GMT
server:Cowboy
x-request-id:hfm969svbqv9oa2jatn5ri641srsht3s
```

### Request Headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:4000
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Referer:http://localhost:4200/signup
```

and my phoenix logs just says

```
[info] OPTIONS /v1/users
[info] Sent 200 in 31µs
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I did modify my router.ex slightly... not sure if it'll make any difference though but here it is

```
defmodule Api.Router do
  use Api.Web, :router

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", Api do
    pipe_through :api

    resources "/organizations", OrganizationController
  end

  scope "/v1", Api.V1, as: :v1 do
    pipe_through :api

    resources "/users", UserController, only: [:create, :show, :update]
  end
end
```

Comment: are you `subscribing` to the `createUser()` method. Update the post with the component code.

Comment: @Aravind updated and yes I am calling subscribe on it.

Comment: Is `plug Corsica` above `plug MyApp.Router`? Can you try temporarily changing `origins` to `"*"` and see if that fixes this?

Comment: @Dogbert Yes, plug Corsica is above plug and I changed it to "*" and it seemed to work... It's sending the POST request now!!!! On that note though, how come when I go to my chrome dev tools I see both OPTIONS & POST request? I've never seen that before.

Comment: Can you try `origins: "http://localhost:4200"` as well once? Does it work?

Comment: @Dogbert tried that as well, works too. dumb mistake by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `origins` value is matched against the `origin` header exactly. Your request is sending the origin value `http://localhost:4200` while you were only allowing `http://localhost`. You need to change the `origins` to `http://localhost:4200` if you want to allow requests from `http://localhost:4200`:

```
plug Corsica, origins: "http://localhost:4200", allow_headers: ["content-type"]
```

Comment: Would you know why it was still sending the 200 OPTIONS reponse? but not the post? I would feel that it would be more reasonable if the 200 OPTIONS failed.

Comment: @LukeXu @ sideshowbarker has explain this at the end of their answer much better than I can. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure the `http://localhost:4000/v1/users` route to send responses that include an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, and that also include the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header with the string "`Content-Type`" in the value, and the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` response header with the string `POST` in the value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS explains in detail.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests explains why the browser sends that `OPTIONS` request, and what response browsers need to that.

> I get a 200 OK OPTIONS but it never sends the POST request.

That’s because if the `OPTIONS` response doesn’t include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers (with values as described above), then the browser stops right there and never sends the `POST`.